# How to remove a £ sign from a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've just finished importing around 17,000 variations into a WooCommerce install, only to find out that all of the price columns contain '£' signs before the prices, which means WooCommerce doesn't recognise them as prices.

To save me having to re-import or edit 17k variations, could anyone tell me how to run (what I guess is) a search and replace across all of the prices, from phpMyAdmin?

Prices are stored within wp_postmeta, under column name meta_value, so I'd essentially just want to run it across this table and column, and nothing else.

Any help is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this query in phpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, '£', '') WHERE meta_value LIKE '%£%'
```

Pleace do a backup after.